# @font-face vitesseSans book not working in ie

Tags: html, css, font-face

I am using the font `vitesseSans book` which is generated by font2web.com in my web page . It's working fine in all major browser except IE.

Here is the code generated by font2web.com

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Conv_VitesseSans-Book_0';
    src: url('fonts/VitesseSans-Book_0.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('fonts/VitesseSans-Book_0.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/VitesseSans-Book_0.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/VitesseSans-Book_0.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Version of the font is 1.002

Comment: i think he means which version of IE

Comment: It is not working with any version of IE (ie 10 to ie 7).

Answer (score 0):

i'am not sure about you `@font-face` syntax, never saw it before, so i give you a syntax that is working for me:

```
@font-face{
 font-family:'Conv_VitesseSans-Book_0';
 src:url('fonts/Conv_VitesseSans-Book_0.eot');
 src:url('fonts/Conv_VitesseSans-Book_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
 url('fonts/Conv_VitesseSans-Book_0.woff') format('woff'),
 url('fonts/Conv_VitesseSans-Book_0.ttf') format('truetype'),
 url('fonts/Conv_VitesseSans-Book_0.svg#Conv_VitesseSans-Book_0') format('svg');
 font-weight:normal;
 font-style:normal;
}
```

SVG needs a #ID to referencing too in the SVG, that is missing.
To target all version old IE, first the default EOT, then the IE foolproof #iefix & format (embedded-opentype).

Maybe this turns out not working for you, maybe your EOT is corrupt by on-line conversion? this is possible, happens some times.

Answer (score 0):

Use : http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ 
then connect the font's

```
    @font-face {
font-family: 'Conv_VitesseSans-Book_0';
src: url('../font/connect generated font.eot');
src: url('../font/connect generated font.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../font/connect generated font.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../font/connect generated font.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../font/connect generated font.svg#connect generated font') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}